# Getting VB Script Error on my redirect script

Tags: vbscript

I am getting a VB compilation error on my redirect script. I placed the redirect script at the root of my server.

```
<%
If InStr(Request.ServerVariables("oldDomain"),"www") = 0 Then
    Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
    Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www."
        & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")
        & Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_URI")
    Response.End
     Response.Redirect("newDomain") 
End if
%>
```

And this is the error I am getting

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0400'
Expected statement
/default.asp, line 5
& Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")
^
```

I am not too familiar with VB. Any help is greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Line continuation in VBScript is done by _.

Sample:

```
Dim aTests : aTests = Array(_
    Array("5-foo, 10 bar", 15) _
  , Array("11 baz", 11) _
  , Array("bad,string", 0) _
  , Array("hello,123,100,   100   ,xxx", 323) _
  , Array("whatever1junk2inbetween10000orafter", 10003) _
)
```